# How to set separate error bar colors with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to manually control the colors of my error bars in a line plot:

```
col_1<-c(1:4, 1:4)
col_2<-c(25, 30, 28, 28, 35, 36, 39, 40)
er_bar<-c(3, 3, 2, 2, 2,4,4,3)
condition<-c("A","A","A","A", "B","B","B","B")
example<-data.frame(col_1, col_2, er_bar, condition)
example

ggplot(example, aes(col_1, col_2, color=condition))+ geom_line(size=0.1)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=col_2-er_bar, ymax=col_2+er_bar), width=.1, color="blue")+ scale_color_manual(values=c("#FF0000", "254117"))
```

gives me a plot with all the error bars the color blue, as specified.  How do I select a separate color for each line?

Comment: Your code is missing the assignment of `col_1`, which prevents me from reproducing the problem.

Comment: Fixed - was missing a line break after the back ticks, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

In order to map the color of your errorbars to the data, you just have to specify `color` as an argument to the `aes` function for that geom.

```r
library(ggplot2)

col_1<-c(1:4, 1:4)
col_2<-c(25, 30, 28, 28, 35, 36, 39, 40)
er_bar<-c(3, 3, 2, 2, 2,4,4,3)
condition<-c("A","A","A","A", "B","B","B","B")
example<-data.frame(col_1, col_2, er_bar, condition)
example
#>   col_1 col_2 er_bar condition
#> 1     1    25      3         A
#> 2     2    30      3         A
#> 3     3    28      2         A
#> 4     4    28      2         A
#> 5     1    35      2         B
#> 6     2    36      4         B
#> 7     3    39      4         B
#> 8     4    40      3         B

ggplot(example, aes(col_1, col_2, color=condition)) + 
  geom_line(size=0.1) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = col_2-er_bar, ymax = col_2+er_bar, color=condition), width=.1) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#FF0000", "254117"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This solution gives error bars the same color as the lines.  I want to control the colors manually.  Is there a way to specify them separtely?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option, though I'd welcome a cleaner method:

```
example2<-example %>%
  mutate(testcol = case_when(
    endsWith(condition, "A") ~ "#F88158",
    endsWith(condition, "B") ~ "#0041C2"
  ))

errorbar_colors<-example2$testcol

ggplot(example, aes(col_1, col_2, color=condition))+ geom_line(size=0.1)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=col_2-er_bar, ymax=col_2+er_bar), width=.1, color=errorbar_colors)+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#FF0000", "254117"))
```